# Identify pyspark table definition for a struct field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

in the Azure databricks I have been using the following syntax for identifying the definition of a spark table.But I have a struct column with more than 50 columns as a result the output is hidden like the screenshot below. Can you help me with the correct syntax please. Thanks in advance.

```
%sql
DESCRIBE table  mak.g1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6ABC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the data to a dataframe.  The code below shows the actual table definition of the hive table.

```
%python

#
#  11 - Show table definition
#

df1 = spark.sql("show create table dim.product")
df1.first().createtab_stmt.replace("\n", " ").replace("  ", "")
```

I am executing the code on the adventure works product dimension.

[image]

This same technique can be done with "describe table".